# How do I cross the inside of the Great Tree?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm inside the Great Tree.  In front of me are two floating platforms, hanging from ropes.  I can leap across to the first platform, but can't leap to the next, or to the ledge on the left.  **How in the world do I get to the second platform?**

I've tried running back and forth to get the platform to swing.  I've tried doing a spin move out of the water, but can't get high enough.  The only result is more stillness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Gust Bellows to push the platforms apart. Then they will rock back to where you can jump on the next one and make it across.

Comment: Note that to get the maximum distance on your swing, you have to use the Bellows twice; use it, let the platform rock back and forth, then use the bellows *again* at the apex of the swing. You'll go further back and further forward on the second swing.